# How do I center over a specific location and then zoom to current location

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Very much a newbie here so please forgive the ignorance.  I have spent some time trying to understand what I am missing but cannot figure it out.

My app centers over Washington State when loading but when I try to zoom to the users current location it puts me at latitude 0 longitude 0.  If I comment out the "// startup: center over WA" section it centers over the users current location and then goToLocation works fine.

How do I get it to center over Washington State and then zoom to the users current location upon clicking goToLocation?

Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadOurAnnotations];
        [mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];

// startup: center over WA
    CLLocationCoordinate2D defaultCoordinate;
    defaultCoordinate.latitude = 47.517201;
    defaultCoordinate.longitude = -120.366211;
    [mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(defaultCoordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(6.8, 6.8)) animated:NO];


}


-(IBAction)goToLocation {
    MKUserLocation *myLocation = [mapView userLocation];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[myLocation location] coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 350, 350);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to use `userLocation` in the `MKMapView` at all, you have to pass `YES` to `setShowsUserLocation` (not `NO`).

Next thing is that after turning `showsUserLocation` on, it may take a few seconds or more for the map view to determine the location and set `userLocation`.  Until then, the location will be nil (giving coordinates of 0,0).

To really know when the userLocation is ready (or updated), implement the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method.  It's also helpful to implement the `didFailToLocateUserWithError` method in case of a problem determining the user location.

However, in your case, you could just do the following in the `goToLocation` method:

```
MKUserLocation *myLocation = [mapView userLocation];
if (myLocation.location == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"user location has not been determined yet");
    return;
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[myLocation location] coordinate];
MKCoordinateRegion region = ... //rest of the code stays the same
```

The animation statements at the end of that method don't do anything, by the way.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Anna. I will tinker with that.